# css выбрать четные элементы по классу

Tags: html, css

Суть задачи

Есть список

```
<ul>
  <li>asd</li>
  <li class="hidden">asd</li>
  <li>asd</li>
  <li>asd</li>
</ul>

.hidden {display: none;}
```

Если применить

```
li:not(.hidden):nth-child(2n) {background: red;}
```

То он применит сначала :nth-child(2n), а потом проверит на наличие класса .hidden. Так вот задача в том чтобы :nth-child(2n) применился к коллекции li:not(.hidden). Как сделать через JS - понятное дело, добавить соответствующие классы для "видимых четных", как это сделать на CSS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как вариант

```css
.block > div {
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100px;
}

.block > div:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div>asd</div>
  <span class="hidden">asd</span>
  <div>asd</div>
  <div>asd</div>
  <span class="hidden">asd</span>
  <span class="hidden">asd</span>
  <div>asd</div>
  <div>asd</div>
  <div>asd</div>
  <div>asd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Похоже, но не то. Надо чтобы элементы использовались одиннаковые. Не span и div а именно все div.

Т.е. .hidden добавляется динамически скриптом на действие пользователя, и когда элементы из набора "скрылись" - то "зебра" для оставшихся видимых - должна сохраниться

Comment: на css - этого не сделать. Тогда вариант, что выше или вариант с явным  классом для четных блоков

Comment: Понял, спасибо, хотелось обойтись без JS.